# Avoid cross browser action in Gulp

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browser-sync

I have created a gulp file for my project, it gets run successfully but when I open it in two browsers and scroll my page in one browser or type something its get reflected in another browser also. I don't know what's wrong.

Here is my gulp.js file

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
rename = require('gulp-rename');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
cache = require('gulp-cache');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
       server: {
           baseDir: "./",
        }
    });
 });

 gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
 });

gulp.task('images', function(){
   gulp.src('assets/images/**/*')
   .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, 
        interlaced: true })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/images/'));
});

gulp.task('styles', function(){
   gulp.src(['assets/styles/**/*.css'])
   .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      this.emit('end');
 }}))
//.pipe(sass())
.pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles/'))
.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
.pipe(minifycss())
.pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles/'))
.pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  return gulp.src('app/**/*.js')
    .pipe(plumber({
       errorHandler: function (error) {
       console.log(error.message);
       this.emit('end');
}}))
.pipe(concat('main.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'))
.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'))
.pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

 gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function(){
     gulp.watch("assets/styles/**/*.css", ['styles']);
     gulp.watch("app/**/*.js", ['scripts']);
     gulp.watch("*.html", ['bs-reload']);
 });


 gulp.task('production', ['browser-sync','bs-
 reload','images','styles','scripts','default']);
```

Comment: This is the expected behaviour when using `browser-sync`

Comment: Then what should I do to avoid...??

Comment: @SuriyaKumar Remove task "bs-reload" and every reference to it. Remove all browserSync.reload() calls.

Comment: I removed but not working @bata.

Comment: @SuriyaKumar don't use browser-sync. Use another HTTP server

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for my question. use "ghostMode: false" to avoid the cross browser action.For Changes like a scroll in one browser will get scroll the page in all browser which has opened your page.

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
   browserSync({
      server: {
          baseDir: "./",
       },
       ghostMode : false
   });
});
```

Thanks,

Suriya

Answer (score 0):

Go to your [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/) settings page (http://localhost:3001 by default) and turn off the sync settings you do not want.

[image]

Also, if you do not want the features Browsersync offers you, why do you use it at all?

Comment: its works fine but when I again start gulp the problem will arise...if you don't mind can you tell me, how to permanently avoid this problem.